# объясните пожалуйста как работает цикл for

Tags: java

```java
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i+=2) { 
    list.add(i, list.get(i));      
}
```

здесь удваиваются слова в списке, например (вова, вова, дима, дима). Объясните пожалуйста как слова удваиваются?

Comment: Непонятно за что минусуют, нормальный вопрос. Прочитайте про list.add(index, element)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, если немного изменить указанный Вами код и на его основе посмотреть, что происходит на каждом шаге цикла, то Вам сразу станет понятно.

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> list =
                Stream.of(
                        "Вова",
                        "Дима"
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i+=2) {
            String name = list.get(i);
            list.add(i, "Новый " + name);

            System.out.println("i: " + i);
            System.out.println("name: " + name);
            System.out.println("names: " +
                    String.join(", ", list));
        }
    }

}
```

Вывод:

```
i: 0
name: Вова
names: Новый Вова, Вова, Дима
i: 2
name: Дима
names: Новый Вова, Вова, Новый Дима, Дима
```